# Remove access from an Azure VNet with a Point-To-Site VPN connection?

Tags: vpn, azure

I've established a VNet on Azure with various associated site-to-site and point-to-site connections, more or less like it says [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/), and it's all working, so far, so good.

But let's say that I've got half a dozen employees accessing a DB server sitting inside the VNet, all coming in through different point-to-site connections.

So how do I remove access for any of those folks? If one of those employees gets fired or quits, ideally, I'd just want to deactivate their account. But that's not how the Azure point-to-site VPN works: you're not coming in using an account, but rather, using an X.509 certificate. Is it possible to deactivate that certificate somehow? Or...? What's the best way to handle this situation? I've searched through the Azure VNet/VPN documentation, and if it's in there anywhere, I've apparently missed it.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/12/09/step-by-step-revoking-and-reinstating-client-vpn-certificates-for-azure-point-to-site-vpns.aspx
This has everything you need. Let me know if it works for you. I'll post it as an answer when I'm not on a mobile device

Comment: Thanks! Throw that into an answer, and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article has a full explanation on the process involved [Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/12/09/step-by-step-revoking-and-reinstating-client-vpn-certificates-for-azure-point-to-site-vpns.aspx) However the following details the basic steps.

## Download Azure Management Certificate

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
```

## Import Azure Management Certificate

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "${env:USERPROFILE}\Documents\Azure.publishsettings"
```

## Select Azure Subscription

```
$subscriptionName = (Get-AzureSubscription).SubscriptionName | Out-GridView -Title "Select Azure Subscription" -PassThru

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
```

## Get Azure subscription information

```
$subscription = Get-AzureSubscription $subscriptionName -ExtendedDetails

$certificate = $subscription.Certificate

$subscriptionId = $subscription.SubscriptionId
```

## Select Azure VNet for which to manage VPN certificates

```
$azureVNet = (Get-AzureVNetSite).Name | Out-GridView -Title "Select Azure VNet" -PassThru
```

## Import saved copy of user's VPN client certificate

```
$certPassword = Read-Host "Enter VPN client certificate password" -AsSecureString

Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "${env:USERPROFILE}\Documents\Azure\P2S VPN\VPN01Client.pfx" -CertStoreLocation Cert:CurrentUser\My -Exportable -Password $certPassword
```

## Select VPN client certificate to Revoke

```
$vpnCertThumbprint = (Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Out-GridView -Title "Select VPN certificate to revoke" -PassThru).Thumbprint
```

## Build web request header

```
$requestHeader = @{"x-ms-version" = "2012-03-01"}
```

## Revoke a VPN Client Certificate

```
$revokeVPNCertUri = "https://management.core.windows.net/$subscriptionId/services/networking/$azureVNet/gateway/clientcertificates/$vpnCertThumbprint"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $revokeVPNCertUri -Certificate $certificate -Method Post -Headers $requestHeader
```

## Confirm Revoked VPN Client Certificates

```
$listRevokedVPNCertUri = "https://management.core.windows.net/$subscriptionId/services/networking/$azureVNet/gateway/clientcertificates"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $listRevokedVPNCertUri -Certificate $certificate -Method Get -Headers $requestHeader

$response.ClientCertificates.Thumbprint
```

Comment: Thank you! It's still a little odd that this very important feature isn't supported in the UI, and that if you, say, fail to save a copy of the certificate, you're SOL, but at least there's A way, even if it's not a very good way.

Comment: I imagine (hope) this will be simplified in the future, perhaps with some integration with Azure AD so you could find the user and simply disable/revoke as you would do with Routing and remote access

Comment: You can do this now through the UI, under Point-to-Site Configuration in the Virtual Network Gateway